# Make the main thread wait for backgroundtasks to finish?

Tags: android, multithreading

In my app, I want users to be able to register themselves. If another user before them has already used that particular emailadress or username the app should say so and not let them upload data to the server.

Right now my problem is, that the main thread does not wait for the two background tasks that check if username or email already exist, but keeps going so every user object is sent to the server, even though they already exist.

Here is my code to check username and email:

```
    public void checkEmailadress(String s){

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("userLogin");
        query.whereEqualTo("emailadress",s);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Iterator itr = arg0.iterator();
            if(itr.hasNext()){
                emailadressInUse = true;
            }else{
                emailadressInUse = false;
            }
System.out.println(emailadressInUse);
    finishSubmittingUser();
        }
        });


    }
```

same goes for checking the username. This works fine. The problem is, boolean emailadressInUse does not change fast enough for the main thread to change action.

here is the method that initiates those two methods

```
public void submitNewUser(View view){
    EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chose_username);
    EditText edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chose_realname);
    EditText edittext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chose_emailadress);
    EditText edittext4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chose_password);

    username = edittext1.getText().toString();
    realname = edittext2.getText().toString();
    emailadress = edittext3.getText().toString();
    password = edittext4.getText().toString();

    checkUsername(username);
    checkEmailadress(emailadress);



    }
```

this is called from inside checkEmail. The two booleans should have changed state by now. And according to System.out.println in checkEmail they did. So why is my method finishSubmittingUser not picking up on that change?

```
public void finishSubmittingUser(){
        if((usernameInUse==false) && (emailadressInUse==false)){
            saveDataChange("realname", realname);

            ParseObject userLogin = new ParseObject("userLogin");
            userLogin.put("username", username);
            userLogin.put("emailadress", emailadress);
            userLogin.put("password", password);
            userLogin.saveInBackground();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogInUserActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(USERNAME, username);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            if(usernameInUse==true){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.username_in_use),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }
            if(emailadressInUse==true){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.emailadress_in_use),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }
        }

    }
```

There must be an easy way to do this that i´m not seeing right now.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Never make the UI `Thread` wait. Is like me asking you to wait to go to the bathroom 30min after taking a laxative...It is mean and wrong.

Comment: As Emmanuel says, you must not make the main thread wait.  Instead, you can push new events onto the main thread when another thread finishes its work.  For your purposes, it sounds like what you may really want to do is lock out part of the functionality until you have a confirmation response, either by disabling controls or even by covering them with a "please wait" spinner dialog.  Bear in mind also that the user could navigate away to some other app while your code is waiting for a response, and at minimum that should not risk getting you into an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 5):

> Make the main thread wait for backgroundtasks to finish?

As Emmanuel said, do not block the main application thread.

> Right now my problem is, that the main thread does not wait for the two background tasks that check if username or email already exist, but keeps going so every user object is sent to the server, even though they already exist.

If "every user object is sent to the server" is something the user does, after registration, simply disable the UI for that (e.g., disable the action bar item) until your registration is confirmed.

If "every user object is sent to the server" is something that happens automatically after a successful registration, then you should not be executing that code *until after a successful registration*.

Comment: @user3457769: "The two booleans should have changed state by now" -- my guess is that you are assuming that your two Parse operations are happening on the same background thread, and perhaps that is not the case.